# Literal translation with grammar notes when analyzing or describing a foreign language

Tags: terminology, translation, interlinear-gloss

I often see this kind of analysis / comparison in linguistic textbooks where they basically provide literal translation of a sentence with grammar notes (like verb tense, noun case etc.). For example:

```
French:
Je    vais     en  ville.  
I  go:PRS:1SG  to  town.

Russian: 
     Idu         v   gorod.
go:IPFV:PRS:1SG  to town:ACC
```

I think it's a great way of demonstrating how a foreign language works so I'd like to find more information about it.

So I was wondering if there is a technical term for this type of analysis / comparison or if there are rules or guidelines for how this procedure should be done properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The kind of  structure you ask about is known as an [interlinear gloss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlinear_gloss). It consist minimally of three lines: the first line being the language being analysed, with segmentable morphemes separated out by hyphens; the second line is in the analysis language and has a gloss (usually a grammatical category label) for each morpheme in the first line and is spaced out so that each glow lines up vertically with the appropriate morpheme in the first line; finally, the third line is a free translation.

This sounds complicated so here is an example to clarify:

```
    1. Latin
    insul  -arum
    island -GEN.PL
    'of the islands'
```

A useful set of conventions for constructing interlinear glosses are [Christian Lehmann's rules for interlinear morphemic glosses](http://www.ling.hawaii.edu/ldtc/website/syllabus/sp06/LehmannGlossing.pdf).

Comment: Superb answer! Another resource you might find useful @stillenat is the Max Planck institute's reasonably concise summary of the Leipzig glossing rules, which i think are probably the most widespread glossing convention in linguistics: http://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/resources/glossing-rules.php